# Can multiple E-Visas be issued while having a valid one?

Tags: visas, russia, saint-petersburg

I am planning to visit Saint-Petersburg for two consecutive weekends and if possible I would like to do so using their new E-Visa system since it's free and quick to use.

I know that an E-Visa is valid for 30 days and that they're single entry only. Also I've read that they cannot be extended or converted into a multi-entry version.

What I cannot find any information about is whether I can apply for a second (or more) E-Visa within the validity period of a pre-existing one with a chance of it to be issued.

Can I use the E-Visa system for this or should I apply for a regular one?

Comment: "An e-visa is issued within 4 calendar days, including week-ends and bank holidays" will you have time to apply again after your first trip?

Comment: @BritishSam Yes but if it cannot be issued I might have to apply for an express visa (a normal one) because I won't have time to apply for an E-Visa and an express one. (Also they are quite expensive).

Comment: Here's an email address info.ruuk@vfshelpline.com also I started an application and it asked for the intended date of entry. But probably best double checking with that email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to apply for a second E-Visa while there is another valid one active, however **if the second one gets issued before entering the country you will have to show it on entry aswell!**

Depending on the border control officer you won't run into too much trouble and he might invalidate the second visa for you even though you do not have it with you (this is what happened to me, but I don't recommend testing this out).

If you have time to apply between entries it is possible to get approved again with a separate e-visa, even if it falls into the validity period of a previous one.